# What do you mean by this rebus?

Tags: rebus

Can you find out what this rebus means?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It must be

> cage nuts
>  A cage nut or caged nut consists of a (usually square) nut in a spring steel cage which wraps around the nut.
>  [image]

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> Mad Max? With the bars representing *max*, which is slang for *maximum security prison*

Answer (score 1):

Silly guess:

> Gone mad behind the bars

Answer (score 0):

This can be the answer, right ?

> A bored and unhappy web designer's view while he is working on the early stage of his new website. 
>  
> Explain : **MAD** : As designer is bored and unhappy due to some other issues(that can be anything), he is really getting mad at his work.
>  
>  **The BARS** : Those are the famous **12 column grid layout** which many developers use in the beginning stage of website designing as a layout to make the website more catchy.